# Redmi boot screen in Chinese - help

Tags: xiaomi, miui, redmi, mi, chinese-language

All of sudden when my 'Redmi Note 9' phone was restarted, I somehow landed on a bootscreen menu which is Chinese language.

Volume Up key is apparently not working on this screen. And I cannot exit to normal bootscreen. Please help [image: redmi note 9 bootscreen].

( Whithout knowing Chinese, I pressed for third last option containing "**eMMC" and I almost fell unconscious seeing the message "Bootdev is busy, Can't format" )

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Chinese/comments/2kzarn/chinese_tablet_menu_could_someone_translate

Comment: there is app called [translate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.translate) it translated [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDnf1.jpg)